# How do you make scrolling pages in a tkinter gui with python 3, like on a website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a small program with the tkinter plugin in python. I want to make a page scrolling as you can do in the browser. Is it possible? and how do you do it?

```
window2 = Tk()
window2.title("RPG SM Beta 0.1")
window2.geometry('150x200')
window2.configure(background="#5C5858")
window2.iconbitmap("Logo.ico")
window2.resizable(False, False)

write1 = Text(window2, height=5, width=17, bg="white")
write1.place(x=6, y=30)

lab2 = Label(window2, text='Lorem ipsum', bg="#5C5858", fg='white', font='none 12 bold')
lab2.place(x=4, y=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most command solution is to use a `Canvas` widget as the container. Anything added to a canvas with the `create_window` method will be scrollable.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @Gatiberi: the method of adding a scrollbar to a canvas is well documented.